# Equivalence in Fatou's lemma.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

> Let $(f_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of measurables functions non-negative. If $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}f_{n}(x)=f(x)$ a.e, then prove that the following statement is equivalent to Fatou's lemma: $$\int_{X}fd\mu \leq \liminf_{n} \int_{X}f_{n}d\mu $$

**My approach:** I know that the Fatou's lemma has by hypothesis that: $(f_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of measurables functions non-negatives, so we have $$\int_{X}\liminf_{n\to \infty}f_{n}d\mu\leq \liminf_{n\to \infty}\int_{X}f_{n}d\mu$$
So, suppose that the hypotheses of Fatou's lemma are fulfilled and that $f_{n}\overset{a.e}{\to}f$, so, we have $$\int_{X}fd\mu=\int_{X}\left(\liminf_{n\to \infty}f_{n}\right)d\mu \leq \liminf_{n\to \infty}\int_{X}f_{n}d\mu, \quad \text{Fatou's lemma}.$$
On the other hand, if  $f_{n}\overset{c.s}{\to}f$ and $$\int_{X}fd\mu \leq \liminf_{n\to \infty} \int_{X}f_{n}d\mu $$ so
$$\int_{X}\liminf_{n\to \infty}f_{n}d\mu\leq \liminf_{n\to \infty}\int_{X}f_{n}d\mu$$

---

**Is it correct?**
**Any suggestion?**

Comment: It is correct and the only thing you need to prove the equivalence is $\lim \inf f_n=f$ a.e. if $f_n \to f$ a.e.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you!  How can I prove this last part?

Comment: A sequence $(a_n)$ of real numbers converges to $a$  if and only if $\lim \inf a_n=a$ and $\lim \sup a_n=a$ .

Comment: Oh! You're right! Thank you!